# typescript configuration on vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this message when I go on my `vscode`:

The path `...\node_modules\typescript\lib` doesn't point to a valid tsserver install.

I've no idea what's wrong. Any ideas?

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": "./ts",
        "outDir": "js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: we could really use more info, like your ts config file maybe. With this much all I could tell you is to check that you have the node modules of your project installed. run an npm install in your project root folder maybe?

Comment: I've added tsconfig file content on post.

Comment: It seems like vs-code is looking for a local npm install of typescript.

Comment: Why do you suggest that? How could I change it?

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps you haven't installed `typescript` in your project, if so - you can do this by `npm install typescript --save-dev`.
And accoring to Visual Studio Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions) - please check path it's use for `typescript.tsdk`, maybe it should look like this:

```
{
   "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Install the version available in your package.json with the command

npm install -g typescript

Then hit ctrl+shift+p

Enter "Open user settings"

In the user settings copy the path of Typescript bin folder from node modules and assign it to "typescript.lib"

"typescript.tsdk": "D:\SampleFolder\Samplesubfolder\Sampleproject\node_modules\typescript\lib",

Note that the path should be separated by "\"

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux (Ubuntu, etc...), open `.vscode/settings.json` and change the `\` char for `/`. Example:

Before:

```json
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib",
```

After

```json
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
```

This change fix the message at startup.